# speed up while loop in R

Tags: r

How could I speed up the following while loop?

```
count <- function(start, stepsize, threshold) {
  i <- 1;
  while ( start <= threshold ) {
    start <- stepsize*i+start;
    i <- i+1;
  }
  return( i-1 );
}

system.time(count(1, 0.004, 1e10))
```

Comment: for this particular problem I would work out the summation by hand -- e.g. you know that sum(i) from 1 to n is n*(n+1) -- then solve the appropriate quadratic equation and adjust.  You could also byte-compile ... is this part of a larger problem, or do you just need to solve this exact problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Working out the sums as in the comment above:

```
## start + S*n*(n-1)/2 = T
## (T-start)*2/S = n*(n-1)
## n*(n-1) - (T-start)*2/S = 0
```

A function to solve this quadratic equation:

```
ff <- function(start,stepsize,threshold) {
  C <- (threshold-start)*2/stepsize
  ceiling((-1 + sqrt(1+4*C))/2)
}
```

This solution takes essentially no time ...

```
> system.time(cc <- count(1, 0.004, 1e10))
   user  system elapsed 
  5.372   0.056   5.642 
> system.time(cc2 <- ff(1, 0.004, 1e10))
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> cc2
[1] 2236068
> cc
[1] 2236068
```

The question is whether this generalizes to the exact problem you need to solve.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do this:

```
recount <- function(start, stepsize, threshold) {
  NewCount <<- floor((threshold-start)/stepsize)
}
(fast <- system.time(recount(1, 0.004, 1e10)))
```

It takes no measurable time.

Without the global variable, here is what it looks like:

```
recount <- function(start, stepsize, threshold) {
  return(floor((threshold-start)/stepsize))
}
(fast <- system.time(NewCount <- recount(1, 0.004, 1e10)))
```

Comment: ?? but this doesn't give the same answer as the OP's test code ... and setting a global variable rather than returning a value is rather unidiomatic ...

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting blog how to speed a loop in R with some tips

[Another aspect of speeding up loops in R](http://menugget.blogspot.dk/2011/11/another-aspect-of-speeding-up-loops-in.html)

This is the example reported in that page

```
NROW=5000
NCOL=100

#Ex. 1 - Creation of a results matrix where its memory
#allocation must continually be redefined
t1 <- Sys.time()
x <- c()
for(i in seq(NROW)){
   x <- rbind(x, runif(NCOL))
}
T1 <- Sys.time() - t1


#Ex. 2 - Creation of a results matrix where its memory
#allocation is defined only once, at the beginning of the loop.
t2 <- Sys.time()
x <- matrix(NA, nrow=NROW, ncol=NCOL)
for(i in seq(NROW)){
   x[i,] <- runif(NCOL)
}
T2 <- Sys.time() - t2


#Ex. 3 - Creation of a results object as an empty list of length NROW. 
#Much faster than Ex. 1 even though the size of the list is
#not known at the start of the loop.
t3 <- Sys.time()
x <- vector(mode="list", NROW)
for(i in seq(NROW)){
   x[[i]] <- runif(NCOL)
}
T3 <- Sys.time() - t3

png("speeding_up_loops.png")
barplot(c(T1, T2, T3), names.arg = c("Concatenate result", "Fill empty matrix", "Fill empty list"),ylab="Time in seconds")
dev.off()

T1;T2;T3
```